# What is a solution to handle multiple same capacity lipo cells in parallel?

Tags: batteries, bms

It seems that BMS's are for batteries in series...

If I have 3 x 1200mAh lipo cells to get pretty much a large 3600mAh 1S pack...

I believe I know that I can't just parallel wire single-cell BMS's together...

So I'm not sure, I was looking around and I could not find a BMS for parallel/1S configuration.

We pretty much just want a "giant" capacity battery pack but in smaller pieces.

I want a single charging input port... and then while in use if a cell is too low it turns off, others keep going, until they all fail or you charge before this scenario happens.

I know there are balancing chargers... we could just do that, but then our cells would be pulled without a protection board/hopefully they drain evenly.

I'm not sure if this is how RC planes do it, where there isn't a smart board on board (most batteries) but the charger deals with balancing.

Thanks for any ideas, looking for off the shelf/small approach.

Comment: What makes you believe that two parallel batteries might drain at different rates? Their voltage will always be equal.

Comment: If you're saying it won't then that's great. I just wanted to be sure. I'm currently going for the dumb approach of charging them individually and then parallel wired (with no circuit guard) until some safe amount of time eg. not 100% usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put cells in parallel, all of them will be discharged evenly, and they will all go flat at exactly the same time. There's no need for a special BMS. Two batteries in parallel are electrically identical to a single, larger battery. You can connect your large, 1-S-many-P battery to a single-cell BMS with an appropriate current rating.

Comment: that's great okay I will do that